# Get an XML from WEB with a SQL DB2 on Iseries

Tags: sql, xml, get, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have to download the XML generated in this page:

https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/api/xmldaily?d=20210923&locale=it

The only parameter is the date in YYYYMMDD format.

I know there are some SQL function to do this, but I don't know how to approce the problem.

EDIT:
I try this:

```
           SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE(
  XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/xmldaily',
  'https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/api/xmldaily?d=20210922&locale=it' AS "doc" ) ,
  'doc/wechselkurse/devise' PASSING XMLPARSE 
  ( DOCUMENT SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETBLOB                                                                                      
  ('https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/dailyrates.xsd' 
        , ''))  
  COLUMNS 
  code Char(3) PATH 'code',
  waehrung char(10) PATH 'waehrung' ,
  kurs decfloat PATH 'kurz'
)
where code = 'USD'
```

But I obtain an empty result, can you help me find the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems, listed below the queries because they kill formatting when not below

```
SELECT * from
    XMLTABLE(
        XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/xmldaily'),
       '$doc/wechselkurse/devise'
        PASSING XMLPARSE 
            (DOCUMENT SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB('https://www.backend-rates.ezv.admin.ch/api/xmldaily?d=20210922&locale=it', '')) as "doc" 
  COLUMNS 
  code Char(3) PATH '@code',
  waehrung char(10) PATH 'waehrung' ,
  kurs decfloat PATH 'kurs'
)
where code = 'usd'
```

- You don't need to add your document to namespaces since it's not a       namesspace
- What you download and parse is not the document but the schema that can validate it
- You have to give a name to your document in the xpath expression, that's the use of as 'doc' (and not '$doc' like in my previous answer)
- You can refer to that name as $doc in the xpath expression
- `code` is an attribute, you can get it's value using `@code`
- `code` values are lowercase

Comment: `http_get()` is brand new, likely the OP may need to use the older [systools.httpGetclob()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=overview-httpgetblob-httpgetclob-scalar-functions)

Comment: Thank's for your help... I edited my question with new infos

Comment: @Charles looks like you're right

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thanks everyone