# Certificate error with SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB

Tags: java, xml, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Based on this: [Get an XML from WEB with a SQL DB2 on Iseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302388/get-an-xml-from-web-with-a-sql-db2-on-iseries)

The program I made works correctly in Interactive mode or in debug, but if I schedule it, I obtain a SQL4302 error:

```
[SQL4302] Java stored procedure or user-defined function SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB, specific name HTTPG00005 aborted with an exception "com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed:   com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the scheduled job under your own user profile?  Or a different one?

According to [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=systools-http-function-overview)
[image]

If I recall correctly, you can have user specific key store configured.  So if you're running under a different profile in batch, that would explain the issue.

Comment: I found the same document, but I use the same profile for scheduled job... do you recommend trying the proposed command?

Comment: Is the server your connection to using a self-signed cert?  Or a cert signed by a CA that might not be in the trust store?

Comment: I don't know.. It's the first time a use a `XMLNAMESPACES`  and `SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB` in an SQLRPG program.  I tried it and it worked... now I found this problem but I don't know anything abount certificate ... How can I check?